# link between my website to another website that demands username and password

Tags: javascript, php, python, authentication

I have 2 websites, first website is an interface for Nagiosxi (software to monitor servers). Person who wants to login, has to insert username and password.

There is an option to build your "own dashboard" in Nagiosxi with the details you are interested about, so I did it. then, I built a one page website with few links to my "own dashboard" in Nagiosxi.

When I click on any link I get the massage: "Your session has timed out." and I can't see any information.

I checked online and I couldn't find any script to do this login from one website to another.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Сan be used oauth authentication between websites [enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth)

Or you can to try dump request.session with login and password and send to authorize another site